# JUnit annotations: TestWatcher.failed() doesn't get invoked when apply() is defined

Tags: junit, annotations

To re-execute only the failed tests after whole suite execution, I created a JUnit rule. If I use TestWatcher.failed() alone, the method is being invoked successfully but if I have apply() defined, failed() is not being invoked. Is it expected to behave so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `apply()` in your own rule, then you override `TestWatcher`'s `apply()`, which calls `failed()`.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my code to call failed() in the catch block.